# Select query on join table - GORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have two tables Agency and Catalog with many-to-many relationship and join table as below.

```
class Agency{
   static hasMany = [catalogs: Catalog]
   static mapping={
    catalogs: joinTable:[name 'agcat']
   }
}

class Catalog{
   String catalog_name    
   static hasMany = [agencies: Agency]
   static belongsTo = Agency

   static mapping={
    agencies: joinTable:[name 'agcat']
   }
}
```

I would like to get the list of Catalogs for given Agency.id = 3 (In my case, catalogs 1 and 2) I have tried this with dynamic finder below but it gives me one row.

```
 Agency agency = Agency.findById(id)
 def catalog = agency ? Catalog.findAllById(agency.id): []
```

My join table agat looks like this-

```
agency_id|catalog_id
2              3
3              1
3              2
4              4
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's right there, no query needed:

```
Agency agency = Agency.get(id)
def catalogs = agency?.catalogs ?: []
```

Note that I'm using `get` and not `findById`. They're basically the same SQL query, but `findById` is a dynamic finder and doesn't use caching by default, and uses it very pessimistically if it does (i.e. it gets cleared a lot) whereas `get` calls are always cached (at least in the 1st-level cache).

Comment: Note that if `Catalog.findAllById(agency.id)` was a valid query you would want to do `Catalog.findAllByAgency(agency)` - think in objects, not ids.